# Django MPTT Filter Only if No Children Exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt, mptt

So I am using MPTT for a Category model in Django, and I was wondering if there is a way to filter a Category if there is no `child`.

models.py:

```
class Category(MPTTModel, TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='children', db_index=True)
```

Categories example in DB:

```
Games > Nintendo > Nintendo 64
Games > Microsoft > Xbox One
```

I want to be able to run a command like this:

```
Category.objects.all().has_no_children()
```

Hoping that it would return `[Nintendo 64, Xbox One]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to get what is called `leaves`. This should help you:

```
Category.objects.filter(lft=F('rght')-1)
```